# Cardview does not match parent using recycler view and Linear Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, layout, cardview

I am using recycler view for my search items but now the cardview appears smaller than how it displays in the design editor when i debugg or at runtime. This is my cardview xml file which when the app is running it will be contained within a recycler view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    
            <GridLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/my_gridLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
                android:columnCount="1"
                android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
    
                <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    app:cardElevation="4dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="16dp"
                    android:layout_margin="2dp">
    
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:padding="15dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
    
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                            android:id="@+id/productImage"
                            android:layout_width="60dp"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            />
    
                        <TextView
                            android:text="productName goes here"
                            android:id="@+id/productCat"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
    
                    </LinearLayout>
    
                </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    
    
            </GridLayout>
    
    
        </LinearLayout>
    
    </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the Activity main xml file that will contain the cardview at runtime.  [I have attached a screenshots of how it appears at runtime here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwY8e.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        app:queryBackground="@drawable/bg_light_sky_blue"
        app:submitBackground="@drawable/bg_light_sky_blue"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_light_sky_blue"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:onClick="OptionsClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24">

        </ImageView>

        <ImageView
            android:onClick="CartClick"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_shopping_cart_24"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginTop="-29dp">

        </ImageView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <SearchView
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:queryHint="@string/search_hint"
                android:id="@+id/mSearch"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_width="349dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded">
                <requestFocus/>
            </SearchView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:id="@+id/myRecycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">


    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Comment: It looks like your card is deeply nested, bad practice if you want performant apps.

That aside why is it so complex? make `CardView` the root of your card and see what happens.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will reduce the nesting

Comment: it worked, thsank you